# Ubuntu getting suspended 5 seconds after showing log on screen

Tags: 15.04, suspend, power-management, startup

Ubuntu getting suspended 5 seconds after showing log on screen. After I wake it, there is no problem. In log I noticed a mem sleep initiation.
also the problem was there when I chose try Ubuntu at the time of installation.
My battery board is not working, so it shows critical battery problem but I disabled that option in power management. I don't think that that i0s the problem.

Adding my system log below:

```
[   71.373127] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[   71.373586] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   71.374861] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[   72.433753] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1062.312 msecs
[   72.434219] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.463 msecs
[   72.437287] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[   72.437331] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[   72.589610] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 155.644 msecs
[   72.589883] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[   72.590367] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[   72.590706] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[   72.592024] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
[   72.592031] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[   72.593738] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
[   72.593899] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[   72.595384] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
[   72.595395] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[   72.596426] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[   72.596484] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[   72.596969] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[   72.597021] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[   72.597022] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x4
[   72.608126] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU1
[   72.610587] CPU1 is up
[   72.610613] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[   72.621716] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU2
[   72.624162] CPU2 is up
[   72.624194] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x5
[   72.635292] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU3
[   72.637761] CPU3 is up
[   72.640194] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[   73.094113] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: MMC controller base frequency changed to 50Mhz.
[   73.094402] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[   73.094426] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[   73.234450] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 156.468 msecs
[   73.234740] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.261 msecs
[   73.378497] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[   73.378699] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   73.393911] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[   73.394033] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   73.394036] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800d77b0c00
[   73.394037] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800d77b0c0c
[   73.394783] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0xffffc90004d9c418
[   73.411401] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   73.411408] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   73.429669] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[   73.597792] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   73.597798] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   73.597851] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   73.597899] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   73.696768] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   73.700766] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[   73.704994] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   73.880509] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.4: Will use DMA mode even though HW doesn't fully claim to support it.
[   73.884506] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: Will use DMA mode even though HW doesn't fully claim to support it.
[   74.264082] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[   74.931214] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[   74.941052] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[   74.951313] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[   74.951575] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   75.901637] PM: resume of devices complete after 2670.303 msecs
[   75.929272] PM: Basic memory bitmaps freed
[   75.929278] Restarting tasks ... done.
[   75.994083] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
[   76.010747] sky2 0000:04:00.0 eth0: enabling interface
[   76.924608] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1e:a6:45:3d:d2
[   76.937680] wlan0: send auth to 00:1e:a6:45:3d:d2 (try 1/3)
[   76.939357] wlan0: authenticated
[   76.941051] wlan0: associate with 00:1e:a6:45:3d:d2 (try 1/3)
[   76.945286] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:1e:a6:45:3d:d2 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   76.945393] wlan0: associated
[  118.789528] audit: type=1400 audit(1437222417.907:26): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/var/lib/gdm/.config/libaccounts-glib/" pid=2446 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=120 ouid=120
[  118.799735] audit: type=1400 audit(1437222417.919:27): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/dconf/profile/gdm" pid=2446 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=120 ouid=0
[  199.520158] audit: type=1400 audit(1437222498.593:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/var/lib/gdm/.config/libaccounts-glib/" pid=3133 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=120 ouid=120
[  199.532900] audit: type=1400 audit(1437222498.605:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/dconf/profile/gdm" pid=3133 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=120 ouid=0
```

Comment: mine is a sony vaio vpceb3m1e

Comment: This has happened to me with Acer aspire notebooks (2 models), with Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu 15.04. It disappears after installing and updating the system. I have no idea why the problem appears in the first place.

Comment: I have the same problem on Acer Aspire One. It did not show up with live USB session, but complete reinstall did not help. Actually, mine does suspend before the login screen, then often also a few seconds in the login process, before password is fully typed in. After login it would also suspend every now and then, before I changed the preferences to not suspend at all. It would be nice if the pre-login and login screen behaviour could be changed as well.